# How can we explain the differences between let and var in global scope of browser?

Tags: javascript, var, arrow-functions, let, global-scope

The result is `10` when I use `var` keyword:

```js
var x = 10;
let foo = {
  x: 90,
  getX: () => {
    return this.x
  }
}

console.log(foo.getX())
```

But `undefined` is the result when I use let keyword:

```js
let x = 10;
let foo = {
  x: 90,
  getX: () => {
    return this.x
  }
}

console.log(foo.getX())
```

I cannot understand why there are two different results, when both of them have the same global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your object method, you used an arrow function, whose context (`this` value) is bound to the function in which you've declared them.

That is, your `getX` function's `this` value will be the global object (`window`).

Then you try to access the `x` property of that object, which is `10` (as global-scope `var` creates properties on the global object) in case of `var`.

However, `let` never creates a property on the global object, therefore in your second example, you get `undefined`.

Try it:

```js
const object = {
  method: () => this
}

console.log(object.method() === window) //true

var foo = 1
let bar = 2

console.log(foo, window.foo) // 1 1
console.log(bar, window.bar) // 2 undefined
```